# Use of Colons In A Method

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Methods with multiple arguments in objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056166/methods-with-multiple-arguments-in-objective-c)

I'm very new to Objective-C I was learning the language by following tutorials online, In one particular tutorial colons(:) used after one another in a method header.

Here's what I'm talking about:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

Can anyone tell me what this method's header represents?

Here's the tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/

I'm a C++ programmer so if you can explain it to me by writing the same code in C++ that would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;
```

The above method is taking 3 aruguments as manager, newLocation, oldLocation of type CLLocationManager, CLLocation, CLLocation respectively.

In C++ or C, it would be something like this :

```
void locationManager(CLLocationManager *manager, CLLocation *newLocation, CLLocation *oldLocation);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!, but what about didUpdateToLocation and fromLocation? are they methods?

Comment: didUpdateToLocation and fromLocation are part of method name.

Comment: @user1880907 : Objective-c uses named arguments as 2nd and 3rd respectively. `sum(int a, int b)` will be in objective-c as `sumFirst:(int)a withSecond:(int)b;`

Comment: Got it!, but I don't have to do it this way right? will there be any difference between `-(void) locationManager :(CLLocationManager *)manager :(CLLocation *)newLocation :(CLLocation *)oldLocation` and `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;` ?

Comment: First one cant be used unless the type are primitives. for object types you must give name.